# Why would you write "ain't"? Isn't it a contraction only used in spoken English?

Tags: slang, contractions, aint

I often hear in English conversation or movies the contraction "ain't" (for "isn't"), but I am more surprised to see it in writing (and I am not referring to a novel, where I can understand its usage: convey common oral expressions in a text)

See this [question (on a technical forum) for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398559/there-aint-listbox-selectionmodenone-is-there-another-way-to-disable-selecti):

> There ain’t `ListBox.SelectionMode=“None”`, is there another way to disable selection in a listbox?

Is it appropriate in that context (formal written technical question)?

Comment: I think that is an inappropriate use of ain't since it doesn't add any value to the sentence but rather makes you wonder why he used it in a context in which one expects a higher register of correct written language. A more appropriate use would be to e.g. express stubbornness, e.g. "that dog just ain't gonna budge, is he?"

Comment: The simple answer is **in that context** it is not appropriate.

Comment: Of course, one of the most famous lyrics from the most erudite America lyricist of the 20th century uses it: [TEXT OF THAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Cain%27t_Say_No)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Ain't" is generally pretty stigmatized; it is widely used in African American Vernacular English and Southern English. If someone uses it in a more formal context, it is likely that they want to convey a casual or insouciant attitude. However, any native English speaker knows what it means, so there should be no issue in terms of communication. On the other hand you might justify not using it on the grounds that it might give non-native speakers some trouble.

Comment: Plus, it was originally the contraction for "am not," so even if someone insists it's not obsolete, it still can't replace "isn't."

Comment: It's always made me awfully said that amn't isn't a word, and that I can't use ain't either.

Comment: *@itrekkie*: Awfully *"said?"* Yes, it is quite depursing. ;-o

Comment: @kitukwfyer: The original words making up the contraction don't prove anything about grammaticality or correctness though.  As one example, just look at the fact that we happily use the construction "aren't I" in place of "am I not", and this is standard.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: I know. Saying "aren't I" bothers me a lot...Much more so than saying/ hearing "ain't it" actually. I intended to just throw the fact out there for general consumption, but my wording doesn't match my intention in retrospect...Oh well. Point taken. :)

Comment: @Charlie Wonderful news: "amn't" is a word. It is accepted by both Oxford Living Dictionary and Merriam Webster, although The Collins Dictionary labels it informal, But it is a contraction of "am not." If you object to using "ain't" to mean" is not", why don't you object to using "aren't" to mean "am not?' I'm right aren't I, you don't object to using aren't as a contraction of am not? The word "amn't" is used chiefly in Ireland and Scotland, but as you observe there is a need for this word, and I hope its use will spread.

Comment: Ain't is used throughout the English-speaking world. An answer that relies on its popularity among a small subset of Americans (indeed, a small subset of the Americans who routinely use the word) as an explanation for its stigma is misleading at best.